# $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=1$ if $x=\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},...$ and $f(x)=0$ else is integrable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, proof-verification

Theorem statement:

> The function $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(x)=1$ for $x=\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},...$  and $f(x)=0$ otherwise is integrable.

My proof:

Partition $[0,1]$ as follows $ 0 \leq ... \leq \frac{1}{2^{k}} \leq ... \leq \frac{1}{4} \leq \frac{1}{2} \leq 1$. Then for minorant step functions $ \phi_{-} \leq f$ we have $\phi_{-} \leq 0$ on $(\frac{1}{2^{j}}, \frac{1}{2^{j-1}}$) and so $\sup I(\phi_{-}) =0$. Similarly we can argue for majorant step functions $\phi_{+} \leq f $ that $\inf I(\phi_{-}) =0$ on $(\frac{1}{2^{j}}, \frac{1}{2^{j-1}}$)  . We conclude that $\inf I(\phi_{-}) = \sup I(\phi_{-}) =0$, so f is indeed Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$.

I have a feeling there is something seriously wrong with this argument. If any one would tell me where (if at all) my argument falls apart, I would be very grateful.

Comment: The main observation that $f$ vanishes on the countable union of open intervals is OK, but the logic can be refined, since the Darboux sums are taken as from inf & sup in closed subintervals.

Comment: Ah ok, so I need to make mention of the endpoints, i.e. the points of discontinuity? Are these even of interest for step functions?

Comment: No from Lebesgue's point of view, but you're doing Riemann here.  It depends whether you can group these jump discontinuities into a finite union of $\epsilon$-neighbourhoods.

Comment: I am not sure I follow, could you perhaps elaborate?

Comment: You mean Lebesgue integrable or Riemann integrable?

Comment: I am talking only about Riemann integrals

Comment: @ wittbluenote well, you have a function $f$ which is continuous everywhere except at a set of points $\{\frac12,\frac14,\frac18,\ldots\}$ which has a finite number of limit points namely $0.$ Enclose $0$ by a small neighborhood and then you have a finite number of discintinuities, so $f$ is Reimann integrable there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Partition $[0,1]$ as follows $$0 \leq ... \leq \frac{1}{2^{k}} \leq ... \leq \frac{1}{4} \leq \frac{1}{2} \leq 1.$$

Note that in Riemann and/or Darboux sums, each partition has *finitely* many partition points.

> We conclude that $\inf I(\phi_{-}) = \sup I(\phi_{-}) =0$.

In Darboux sums, one has to take sup/inf from *closed* subintervals formed by adjacent partition points.  Therefore, your argument is flawed.

There's no denying that the function values $f(a), f(b)$ at the endpoints *won't* affect the value of the definite integral $\int_a^b f$ provided that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$.  To see this, suppose that $f$ is bounded on $[a,b]$ by $M > 0$.  Changing $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ only affects the blue area (, which is $4M\epsilon$), which can be set to arbitrarily small.

[image: Riemann integrability endpoints]

Now, to fix your proof, you only need to choose *finitely* many appropriate blue strips with arbitrarily small area to cover the jump discontinuities.  Since those discontinuities are "concentrated" at $x = 0$, you don't need the blue strip at the right endpoint $x = 1$.  You'll only need one blue strip at the left endpoint $x = 0$.  That will cover the discontinuities except at $x = 2^j$, where $j = 1, \dots, \lfloor -\log_2\varepsilon \rfloor, \lceil -\log_2\varepsilon \rceil$.  The last two candidates of $j$ might get covered by the left blue strip, but I'm adding them as well.  Cover these discontinuities too with non-overlapping blue strips with *thinner* width, so that the total area of blue strips is still arbitrarily small.  This is possible since there're only finitely many possible $j$, and the range of $j$ only depend on $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove the following results step by step:

> **Theorem**: Let $f:[a, b] \to\mathbb{R} $ be a *bounded* function and let $D$ be the set of its discontinuities.
>
> - If $D=\emptyset $ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.
> - If $D$ is *finite* then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.
> - If $D$ has a *finite* number of limit/accumulation points in $[a, b] $ then $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b] $.

For the function in question the third criterion applies as the set of discontinuities has only one limit point $0$ and thus the function is Riemann integrable.

---

**Note**: The theorem above does not cover the case when $D$ is countable. The result holds in this case too and can be proved without measure theory but with more difficulty.